# Link on sidebar only shows at edges of text

Tags: html, css

I want to link both image and text on the sidebar to new page.
The "hovering hand" only appears along the edge of the page.

- Sidebar to the right edge of view.
- Two vertical blocks within sidebar.
- Three segments within each block, left is picture, right is text.

I want to have the "hovering hand" show over the whole segment of picture and text.
Now it only shows only to the right border of the segment.
And when the window is narrowed, the "hovering hand" won't show at all.

Could it be the nested structure here somehow mask over the segment and the link is hidden?
I tried with putting   over three layers: link over image only, link over the segment, link over the block. None worked normal. Thank you for your help!

```css
#menu{
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top: 50px;
    width: 14em;
}

.vertical-1-of-2{
    height:50%;
}

.consumerstudies{
    border-left: 5px solid #008388;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

#menu p{
    color:#553b2f;
    font-size:60%;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align: left;
}

.project-photo img{
    border-radius: 10%;
    max-width: 90%;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
                <div class="nav vertical-1-of-2">
                    <div class="consumerstudies">
                        <h3>Consumer Studies</h3>
                         <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/projects.html" class="project-photo">
                            <div class="sidebar">
                                <div class="col span-1-of-4">
                                    <img src="vendors/images/cookie.jpg" alt="finding_perfect_chocolate_chip_cookie" style="width:100%">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col span-3-of-4">
                                    <h4>Cookie Recipe</h4>
                                    <p>Find the perfect chocolate chip cookie recipe</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It seems working to me: [See this](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/GRNqGLQ)

Comment: Thank you so much for confirming it's working. I figured it out why the links are not working. The main panel is covering it. I used to set it to width: 60em and it extended to part of the side bar. Later I changed it to width: 48em; and all the links on the image and text are fining again. Thanks for helping me out!